# SQL Server Cannot drop database <dbname> because it is currently in use... but no sessions displayed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

When I try to drop a database I get the error "Cannot drop database "dbname" because it is currently in use". However, when I run `sp_who2`, there are definitely no sessions connected to this database.  I've also set the database to `single_user mode with rollback immediate`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Since I can't "answer" this presently, see [my answer to this other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/274503/26074). The error message you saw is a bit misleading. Zero spids may be "connected" to the database catalog, but at least one spid still holds a shared DB lock.

Comment: SSMS has a simpler way to do this. From object explorer, right click on database > Delete. From the delete dialog, check `close existing sessions`. Unless you are dropping databases from a script,  SSMS is the way to go.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure you don't have dependencies like database snapshots on the db you want to remove. Though, the error message would look otherwise. 
Are you sure that there is no hidden process that is connecting to your database? A good approach would be to run a script which kills all sessions and immediately after rename the database to another name and then drop database.

create a cursor based on this select:

```
  select  d.name , convert (smallint, req_spid) As spid
      from master.dbo.syslockinfo l, 
           master.dbo.spt_values v,
           master.dbo.spt_values x, 
           master.dbo.spt_values u, 
           master.dbo.sysdatabases d
      where   l.rsc_type = v.number 
      and v.type = 'LR' 
      and l.req_status = x.number 
      and x.type = 'LS' 
      and l.req_mode + 1 = u.number
      and u.type = 'L' 
      and l.rsc_dbid = d.dbid 
      and rsc_dbid = (select top 1 dbid from 
                      master..sysdatabases 
                      where name like 'my_db')
```

issue inside cursor:

```
SET @kill_process =  'KILL ' + @spid      
            EXEC master.dbo.sp_executesql @kill_process
                   PRINT 'killed spid : '+ @spid
```

after the cursor is closed and deallocated:

```
sp_dboption 'my_db', 'single user', 'TRUE'

go

sp_renamedb 'my_db', 'my_db_old'

go

DROP DATABASE MY_DB_OLD
```

Comment: Thanks for the code - that might work. What I don't understand is, what is a "hidden" session? I would have thought sp_who and the other metadata (DMVs) would show *all* sessions, otherwsie what use are they?

Comment: Yes normally you should be able to see all active/nonactive through sp_who or querying the sysprocesses table from master db. By hidden i meant a process that reconnects from an application service. Cheers.

Comment: This is antiquated for multiple reasons: (1) old-style joins (2) backward compatibility views (3) a cursor and dynamic SQL to run a bunch of KILL commands when a single ALTER will do (4) deprecated procedures like sp_dboption.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this answers the question - the questioner is asking why this is happening, not how to solve. The answer provided works, but I still don't know what's keeping me from deleting a database. @AaronBertrand mentioned "even Object Explorer could be the culprit" which actually ended up being the reason for ONE of the databases, but how could I tell it was Object Explorer for sure?

Comment: this gives me the error "Cannot use KILL to kill your own process"

Answer (score 106):

A session connected to another database might have an open transaction that also affects your database - sp_who2 will only show one database. It could also be something as simple as Object Explorer or Object Explorer Details open in SSMS, which again would only show one database in sp_who2.

Don't bother trying to *find* the session that is responsible; just kill them all with one statement (and make sure it isn't your copy of SSMS that is connected, e.g. another query window, Object Explorer, etc.):

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
```

Now you will be able to drop it, and do that using DDL, not the UI:

```
DROP DATABASE dbname;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this worked. But I'm just having difficulty living with this solution: why is it that I cannot drop some databases due to this error? I have some databases that have not been touched for a year and there is no process or ostensible transaction that are connected to them. Could you give me some hints to help me find potential services, or transactions or anything that's connected to these databases?

Comment: Actually, all I had to do was `USE master`, then `DROP DATABASE dbname`. Apparently all that's needed is to just "use" something else, to release the db.

Comment: @vapcguy That's only true if your current query window is the only connection. This is not typically the case (and which is why my answers states "and make sure it isn't your copy of SSMS that is connected").

Answer (score 21):

How about just seeing what SSMS does when you use the UI but tell it to issue a script for the action?  Here is what SSMS does when you right click the DB and choose Delete, then check the box to close existing connections:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'yourdbname'
GO

USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [yourdbname] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

USE [master]
GO

DROP DATABASE [yourdbname]
GO
```

Answer (score 19):

What's your current database when you issue the `DROP` command? Try this:

```
use master
go
drop database mydb
go
```

Also be sure that you are connected as `sa` and not `dbo` on whichever database you want to drop.

Comment: I'm definitely connected to master. I shouldn't have to be connected as sa to drop a database. This looks to me like a bug - it's not displaying a session, or it thinks there's a session in use but there isn't.

Comment: I just got caught out with this - tried to run the drop script with the context set to the database from the sqlcmd prompt!  Doh

Answer (score 5):

I have faced this situation many times and below is what I do :

**When obvious methods do not work .....(just like in your situation) :**

Find out the database ID from sysdatabases.

Then execute - `sp_lock` that will show all the locks on the instance along with spid and dbid.

Kill the spids with the dbid that you are trying to offline or drop.

Though, the process is a bit manual, it can be automated as below :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp;
create table #temp (spid int
                , dbid int
                ,ObjId bigint
                , IndId bigint
                ,Type varchar(5)
                ,resource varchar(max)
                ,Mode varchar(5)
                ,status varchar(10));
declare @dbid int
select @dbid =DB_ID(db_name())

insert into #temp
exec sp_lock

select * from #temp
where dbid = @dbid
```

Answer (score 4):

Found really simple answer on StackOverflow that worked first time for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7469167/261405

Here's the SQL from that answer:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName nvarchar(50)
SET @DatabaseName = N'YOUR_DABASE_NAME'

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL,'') + 'Kill ' + Convert(varchar, SPId) + ';'
FROM MASTER..SysProcesses
WHERE DBId = DB_ID(@DatabaseName) AND SPId <> @@SPId

--Use this to see results
SELECT @SQL 
--Uncomment this to run it
--EXEC(@SQL)
```