# DBCC INPUTBUFFER shows Event Type as Language Event for an unused Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dbcc, session

In my production SQL Server 2016 server,i had few dummy databases created as part of migrating from SQL Server 2008.
I was cleaning up all the unwanted databases and i dropped few databases.But when i tried to drop an unused database ,i get the error message "Cannot drop the database as it is currently in use".
So i checked the process/session using that database.
I see that `spid 144` uses it and when i did `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(144)`,i see an `Event Type as Language Event`.

[image]

I am not sure what it means.

I tried to kill the spid earlier ,but in few seconds a new session started and i am still not able to drop that database.

This particular database is not in use for atleast 6 months now and that is why i tried to KILL the process using that db,cause i was sure that it won;t affect any.

Any idea why a new session is getting created and the database is always in use.

Comment: I think the title of your question is off. Are you trying to figure out how to drop a database with active connections, or bypass reading [`DBCC INPUTBUFFER` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-inputbuffer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: I want to drop the database,but more importantly i want to know what that session/process is doing.That is why i gave the title like that.

Comment: Well, the EventInfo column has a lot more useful information for you than the EventType column, so I'm not sure why the focus on the `Language Event`.

Answer (score 2):

Your session has a connection context to the database. In order to drop a database, you need to remove all connections (including your own query window & Object Explorer connections):

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
DROP DATABASE dbname;
```

(See also [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2387/1186).)

This is much cleaner and immediate than playing `KILL-a-spid` (whack-a-mole) for individual sessions and hoping you get your alter in before another session establishes connectivity.

We can't tell you *why* this session is getting created, something that is calling `dtb.compat...` which isn't anything built into SQL Server, so it must be a user or some application. You can get more detail when you catch this query in the act, like host name, app name, and other details, by looking at `sys.dm_exec_connections`, `sys.dm_exec_connections`, `sys.dm_exec_requests`, etc.

Your query against `sysprocesses` is problematic for two reasons. (1) `dbid` there is unreliable. A session can definitely hold locks against a database with a different `dbid` indicated there (think cross-database joins). (2) [`sysprocesses` is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql):

[image]

As for the `Language Event` question, this just means that the last command that session sent to SQL Server was query text. The other option (other than `No Event`) is an `RPC Event`, which in simplest terms means a procedure call. See the [`DBCC INPUTBUFFER` topic in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-inputbuffer-transact-sql) for more details.